# Publish-Subscriber using SimpleInjector IoC

Tags: c#, design-patterns, simple-injector

I've been thought about implementing event model in my web app.

The approach I  need to implement is:

1. Get data from DB;
2. Pass it to Grab method and collect data;
3. Convert result to my suitable data and build email, log message lists;
4. Notify user if needed by email service; (after that we need to change bool flag in DB that user was notified)
5. Write all grabbing logs into some store;
6. Add grabbed data to DB.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22341992/using-registerinitializer-to-wire-event-handlers/22344331#22344331) answer I decided to use mentioned sample. But I've stacked upon how to wire up events and pass data that I need to handle. I have a class whish grabs some info from the internet:

```
public interface IScheduleService
{
    void ParseWebData(int userId);
}

public class ScheduleService : IScheduleService
{
    IQueryHandler<ProductGrabbedInfoByUserQuery, IEnumerable<ProductGrabbedInfo>> GrabberQuery;
    IEventPublisher publisher;

    List<string> logMessages = new List<string>();
    List<string> emailMessages = new List<string>();


    public ScheduleService(IQueryHandler<ProductGrabbedInfoByUserQuery, IEnumerable<ProductGrabbedInfo>> GrabberQuery,
                           IEventPublisher publisher)
    {
        this.GrabberQuery = GrabberQuery;
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public void ParseWebData(int userId)
    {
        // получаем данные из БД
        var qry = new ProductGrabbedInfoByUserQuery { UserId = 1 }; // пока что один юзер
        var data = GrabberQuery.Handle(qry).ToList();
        if (data.Any())
        {
            // собираем информацию
            GrabberEngine ge = new GrabberEngine(BrowserType.Mozilla);
            ge.Grab(data);
            // преобразовываем в наш вид с собиранием логирования и ошибок
            var converted = ConvertFromGrabbedInfo(data);
            // HERE I THINK WE SHOULD CALL publisher.Publish(new GrabbingCompletedEvent{...}) to execute 3 points below:
            // 1. Send email message using List<string> emailMessages info
            // 2. Log messages using List<string> logMessages info
            // 3. add collected data to DB
        }
    }
}
```

If we need to have event data being maximum small then we need to store some small values:

```
public class GrabbingCompletedEvent : IDomainEvent
{
    public readonly string JobId;
    public readonly int UserId;

    public GrabbingCompletedEvent(string JobId, int UserId)
    {
        this.JobId = JobId;
        this.UserId = UserId;
    }
}
```

Ok, then I think we need to create Event handlers:

```
public class NotifyEmailGrabbingCompletedEventHandler : IEventHandler<GrabbingCompletedEvent>
{
    private IEmailService emailService;
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private IEnumerable<string> messages;
    private IQueryHandler<GetByPrimaryKeyQuery<User>, User> UserQuery;

    public NotifyEmailGrabbingCompletedEventHandler(IEmailService emailService, 
        ILogger logger, 
        IEnumerable<string> messages, 
        IQueryHandler<GetByPrimaryKeyQuery<User>, User> UserQuery)
    {
        this.emailService = emailService;
        this.logger = logger;
        this.messages = messages;
        this.UserQuery = UserQuery;
    }

    public void Handle(GrabbingCompletedEvent e)
    {
        var user = GetUserInfo(e.UserId);
        emailService.Send(user.Email, string.Join(Environment.NewLine, messages));
        emailService.SetDelivered(true);
    }

    private User GetUserInfo(int userId)
    {
        var cmd = new GetByPrimaryKeyQuery<User> { PK = userId };
        return UserQuery.Handle(cmd);
    }
}

public class LogGrabbingCompletedEventHandler : IEventHandler<GrabbingCompletedEvent>
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private IEnumerable<string> messages;

    public LogGrabbingCompletedEventHandler(ILogger logger, IEnumerable<string> messages)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    public void Handle(GrabbingCompletedEvent e)
    {
        foreach (var message in messages)
        {
            this.logger.Log(message);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is how could I pass logger instances, lists of messages and queryHandlers to current handlers? Am I right to pass such parameters in event handlers constructor? The first variant that came to me was to add this data as properties into event class, but it seems like bad decision. Could you, please explain what design approach would be better for such situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an IoC container like SimpleInjector then the event handler class should be resolved by the container, and in turn all of its dependencies should be resolved from the container. This keeps the event handler decoupled from the class that raises the event. The event class would only need to contain the data that describes the event, not any other dependencies.

So yes, the event handler's constructor would be the right place to put its dependencies, just like with the class that's raising the event.

I use an `IEventBus` interface which I inject into classes - pretty much the same as your `IEventPublisher`. The implementation resolves implementations of `IEventHandler<T>` that are registered with the container. That way everything gets resolved from the container.

[Here's an implementation I use](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/04/01/event-bus-implementation.html). The event bus itself is container-agnostic. If you're using DI it requires an `IHandlerProvider` implementation to resolve handlers using the container. My implementation uses Windsor. But the design is that you could use a different container to resolve handlers. You would just have to write a different implementation of `IHandlerProvider`.

Comment: But how to pass my `List<string> logMessages` and `List<string> emailMessages` to event handlers. Do I need then to keep them in GrabbingCompletedEvent as properties? Doesn't it seems that event data is overhead and redundant? Otherwise I don't know how else to pass the data to the eventhandlers...

Comment: If it's the data that the event handlers should be responding to then yes, you should pass it. But you might want to add `.AsReadOnly()` so that you're passing a read-only collection. Otherwise one of the event handlers could modify the collection.

Comment: Ok, thanks, haven't thought about it. One more question, Scott. Do I need to create third event handler for inserting grabbed data into DB or my schedule service can be responsible for this? And in that variant I simply wrap publisher method in async task and then will do insert.

Comment: I didn't really follow the logic of it in that much detail. Typically I use domain events for things that are "side effects" of what the class does. If a primary behavior of your class to ensure that the data is written somewhere then you may want to have it depend on another class that does that. If it's a side effect then you could just raise an event and have another handler that does that.